# Browsing localhost:80 Doesn't Display Default Website in IIS7

Tags: iis, iis-7.5

Way before now, there was no problem with my IIS configuration. But recently as I tried to test my asp.net application on my browser (Google Chrome), I get unable to connect to the internet instead of my web application on my development machine.

I later discovered localhost:80 was not displaying the IIS default website anymore. I changed the port from 80 to 8080, 81 and 85 but all to no avail.

I have checked to ensure that iis is still running and nothing is blocking port 80. Also ran `telnet localhost 80` but couldn't open the connection. Please I need help as I do not know what else to do. Thanks.

Comment: What error message do you receive in browser?

Comment: @Ali I get this error: **Unable to connect to the Internet**

Comment: Do you receive this message in all browsers?

Comment: if firefox connects but not chrome (and IE) , check this out: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee250701(v=bts.10).aspx

Comment: @Ali, Yes I get the same message on IE. But what I notice is if I try [link](http://127.0.0.1:80), it shows the default iis7 page. But using localhost and it fails.

Comment: I don't have firefox installed on my machine. Kindly note that this used to work before on both initially until recently. I have no idea what happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to IIS root through 127.1.1.1 but not through http://localhost , a software of spyware might edited your **hosts** file. open the following file using notepad (run notepad as administrator and look for all files (not .txt files only))

```
(C:/)>/windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts
```

and then make sure if the correct IP is assigned to localhost. you should have (or add) this line to hosts:

```
127.1.1.1   localhost
```

Comment: Exactly what I did before you responded. Thanks all the same.